# Clear cache when reseting password with securesocial

Tags: caching, cookies, playframework, session-cookies, securesocial

I'm using Play 2.3.9 and securesocial 3.0-M3 to build my web app.

I am having an issue when my users are resetting their passwords. Once reset they cannot use the new password to log into the application.

However, when they use a third party access (in my case it's an Outlook plugin) they can use the new password.
It looks like a cache issue, but I don't know how to clear the cache when resetting the password. 
I don't know if it's related, but I set the cookie idleTimeoutInMinutes=720 and absoluteTimeoutInMinutes=1440 in securesocial.cookie (securesocial.conf)

Do you have any idea what it could be?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Can you make sure your UserService is saving/retrieving things properly? Passwords are not cached by the module.